# Laravel Email Verification Template Location

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have been reading from the documentation about the new feature of laravel the email verification. Where can I locate the email template that is sent to the user? It does not show here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification#after-verifying-emails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually they do not use any blade or template files. They create notifications and write code for it in notifications.

Comment: Where is that code ? Where is the html tags in code?

Answer (score 45):

Laravel uses this method of [VerifyEmail](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.html) notification class for send email:

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    if (static::$toMailCallback) {
        return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable);
    }
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(Lang::getFromJson('Verify Email Address'))
        ->line(Lang::getFromJson('Please click the button below to verify your email address.'))
        ->action(
            Lang::getFromJson('Verify Email Address'),
            $this->verificationUrl($notifiable)
        )
        ->line(Lang::getFromJson('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
}
```

[Method in source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php#L37).

If you wanna use your own Email template, you can extend Base Notification Class.

## 1) Create in `app/Notifications/` file `VerifyEmail.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail as VerifyEmailBase;

class VerifyEmail extends VerifyEmailBase
{
//    use Queueable;

    // change as you want
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        if (static::$toMailCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable);
        }
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::getFromJson('Verify Email Address'))
            ->line(Lang::getFromJson('Please click the button below to verify your email address.'))
            ->action(
                Lang::getFromJson('Verify Email Address'),
                $this->verificationUrl($notifiable)
            )
            ->line(Lang::getFromJson('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
    }
}
```

## 2) Add to User model:

```
use App\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
```

and

```
/**
 * Send the email verification notification.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $this->notify(new VerifyEmail); // my notification
}
```

---

Also if you need blade template:

> laravel will generate all of the necessary email verification views
>   when the `make:auth` command is executed. This view is placed in
>   `resources/views/auth/verify.blade.php`. You are free to customize
>   this view as needed for your application.

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification#verification-views).

Comment: This is the verification page's template, not the e-mail. The e-mail was sent out by ```vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail::toMail()``` method.

Comment: @laze Thanks, I wrote how to override the base email.

Comment: Yes, this is OK now, that's the real solution! ;)

Answer (score 21):

Answer in comment already. Sent by the `toMail()` method.

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail::toMail();
```

For template structure and appearance; take a look at this locations also and you can also publish to modify the template:

```
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Notifications\resources\views\email.blade.php
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\resources\views\
```

To publish those locations:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

After running this command, the mail notification templates will be located in the `resources/views/vendor` directory.

Colors and style are controlled by the CSS file in `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes/default.css`

Comment: Please, `email.blade.php` is a component, what template uses this component and how can i customize that? thanks

Answer (score 6):

Also, if you want to translate standard mail [VerifyEmail](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.html) (or other where use Lang::fromJson(...)), you need create new json file in resources/lang/ and name it ru.json, for example.
It may contain (resources/lang/ru.json) text below and must be valid.

```
{
  "Verify Email Address" : "Подтверждение email адреса"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Look I do that very easy
> do the following steps :

---

In Route File

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

> In AppServiceProvider.php File

```
namespace App\Providers;
use App\Mail\EmailVerification;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use View;
use URL;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Config;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Override the email notification for verifying email
        VerifyEmail::toMailUsing(function ($notifiable){        
            $verifyUrl = URL::temporarySignedRoute('verification.verify',
            \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(\Illuminate\Support\Facades 
            \Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
            [
                'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
            ]
        );
        return new EmailVerification($verifyUrl, $notifiable);

        });

    }
}
```

> Now Create EmailVerification With Markdown

```
php artisan make:mail EmailVerification --markdown=emails.verify-email
```

Edit The EmailVerrification as you want and the blade file

```
class EmailVerification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $verifyUrl;
    protected $user;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($url,$user)
    {
        $this->verifyUrl = $url;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $address = 'mymail@gmail.com';
        $name = 'Name';
        $subject = 'verify Email';
        return $this->to($this->user)->subject($subject)->from($address, $name)->
        markdown('emails.verify',['url' => $this->verifyUrl,'user' => $this->user]);
    }
}
```

> in the blade file change the design as you want and use verifyUrl to display the verification link and $user to display user information

thanks, happy coding :)

Comment: Perfect, this solution was I searched all the time!

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, do you know a similar method for the forgot email template?

Answer (score 0):

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\resources\views\html
```

You will find the Laravel default email template in this file location.

Answer (score -1):

If a notification supports being sent as an email, you should define a toMail method on the notification class. This method will receive a $notifiable entity and should return a  Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage instance. Mail messages may contain lines of text as well as a "call to action".

```
/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $url = url('/invoice/'.$this->invoice->id);

    return (new MailMessage)
                ->greeting('Hello!')
                ->line('One of your invoices has been paid!')
                ->action('View Invoice', $url)
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

You can use the laravel e-mail builder as documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#mail-notifications. Laravel will take care of the e-mail view.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22809036)

Comment: @Zoe I think it's highly unlikely that Laravel removes old documentation in the coming years since they have a very good track record on keeping old documentation online. I updated my post.

Comment: @scre_www what the source of the link is is irrelevant - the rules are universal. I've retracted my flag though