# I want to make changes to the Laravel forge vendor folder

Tags: laravel, email, forge

I want to change the Laravel validation email template. However, the vendor folder is not installed in the github store and I cannot edit the codes from within laravel forge. Is there another way to do this? I don't know much about server management. Waiting for help, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Email Verification Template Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231870/laravel-email-verification-template-location)

Comment: Never edit anything in `vendor`. It'll be wiped out the next time you deploy. See the answer that deals with overriding the default template at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52232055/1902010.

Comment: (Another possible dupe, this one Laravel 5.7 specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416804/how-to-customize-the-email-verification-email-from-laravel-5-7)